# Regarding definition of dereferencing and member selection operators in smart pointer

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, smart-pointers, dereference

In smart pointer implementation, dereferencing operator and member selection operators are always defined as below.

```
T& operator* () const     // dereferencing operator
{
    return *(m_pRawPointer); 
}

T* operator->() const     // member selection operator
{
    return m_pRowPointer;
}
```

I don't quite understand why the former is returned by reference, the latter is returned by pointer. Is it just to differentiate them or some other reasons?
To be more specific, can I make dereferencing operator returns by pointer, while the other one returns by reference?

Comment: `operator*()` can return whatever you feel it should and the only rule for `operator->()` is that it must return a type for which calling `operator->()` is well formed. Iterator classes like to simulate pointers in that deferencing them with `operator*()` returns an lvalue. So a reference is usually the return type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why the former is returned by reference

So that the expression `*thing` gives an *lvalue* denoting an object of type `T`, just as it would if `thing` were a pointer.

> the latter is returned by pointer

Because that's how the language is specified. Note that you never use the result of `->` directly, but always in an expression of the form `thing->member`.

If `thing` is a class type, that's evaluated by calling `operator->`, then applying `->member` to the result of that. To support that, it must return either a pointer, or another class type which also overloads `operator->`.

> can I make dereferencing operator returns by pointer

Yes, but that would be rather confusing since it would behave differently to applying the same operator a pointer. You'd have to say `**thing` to access the `T`.

> while the other one returns by reference

No, because that would break the language's built-in assumptions about how the overloaded operator should work, making it unusable.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the dereference operator returns by reference and the member selection operator returns by pointer is to line up the syntax of using a smart pointer with the syntax of using a raw pointer:

```
int* p = new int(42);
*p = 7;

std::unique_ptr<int> p(new int(42));
*p = 7;
```

You could absolutely make your dereference operator return anything you like:

```
struct IntPtr {
    int* p;

    int* operator*() { return p; }
};
```

But that would be pretty confusing for your users when they have to write:

```
IntPtr p{new int{42}};
**p = 7;
```

The arrow operator is a little different in that [over.ref]:

> An expression `x->m` is interpreted as `(x.operator->())->m`

So you have to return something on which you can call `->m`, otherwise you'll just get an error like (from gcc):

> error: result of 'operator->()' yields non-pointer result